# Multiplicity of zeros of partial sums of the Dirichlet Eta function

Tags: nt.number-theory, dirichlet-series

I am studying ways to approach the problem of the multiplicity of zeros of the partial sums of the Dirichlet Eta functions:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{K}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{s_o}} = 0
$$
more in particular, whether it can be proved that the above implies that its first derivative cannot vanish (i.e. multiplicity = 1):
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{K}\frac{(-1)^{n} \log n}{n^{s_o}} \neq 0
$$
considering $s_o = \sigma_o + i t_0$, and substituting $t_o \log n = a_n$, we can reformulate in a slightly more general fashion:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{K}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\cos a_n}{n^{\sigma_o}} = 0 \;\;\;\;\;\; AND \;\;\;\;\;\;\sum_{n=1}^{K}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\sin a_n}{n^{\sigma_o}} = 0 
$$
would it also imply that it cannot be (let us consider $t_o \neq 0$)
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{K}\frac{(-1)^{n} a_n\cos a_n}{n^{\sigma_o}} = 0 \;\;\;\;\;\; AND \;\;\;\;\;\;\sum_{n=1}^{K}\frac{(-1)^{n} a_n\sin a_n}{n^{\sigma_o}} = 0 \;\;\;\;\;\; ?
$$
whereby $a_n$ is now simply defined as a monotonically increasing sequence of positive real numbers.

I am just wondering whether this kind of more general sums have ever been studied in a systematic way. The aim is to verify whether that may help, or whether it is instead adding even more complexity to an already difficult problem.

**First Edit** :
I have in the meantime realised that the above conditions may also be visualized in a more intriguing way by simply switching the signs in the first one (we are considering the = 0 case anyway). Referring to the $\sin$ finite sums (in this example the sum ends at odd $k$), whereby "........." is a short notation for the corresponding finite sum of cosine terms:
$$
0\, + \, \frac{\sin a_2}{2^{\sigma_o}} \, - \, \frac{\sin a_3}{3^{\sigma_o}}  \, + \, .... \, - \, \frac{\sin a_k}{k^{\sigma_o}} = 0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; AND \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; "........." 
$$
would it also imply that it cannot be (let us consider $t_o \neq 0$)
$$
0\, + \, a_2\frac{\sin a_2}{2^{\sigma_o}} \, - \, a_3\frac{\sin a_3}{3^{\sigma_o}}  \, + \, .... \, - \, a_k\frac{\sin a_k}{k^{\sigma_o}} = 0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; AND \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; "........."  \;\;\;\;\;\; ?
$$
Of course, sufficient conditions can then be obtained by restricting to only parts of the above relatonships, such as for example limiting our examination to the the two sines sums only. Indeed, myself I am unable to imagine how there could ever exist a monotonically increasing sequence $a_n$, of positive real numbers, such that the above two finite sums of sine terms could both vanish at the same time (could not find any counterexample). Yet, I am unable to find a way to prove it.

That would also prove that zeros of the Dirichlet Eta Function (and thus of the Riemann Zeta Function) must be of multiplicity 1, through a straightforward application of Hurwitz's Theorem (this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis) ).

Comment: I shall clarify that I am considering only positive $t_o \neq 0$ because of the symmetry of complex conjugate zeros.